# Pattern for writing Chart Components

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have to write a chart component from scratch in Silverlight 3 and wonder if anybody knows if there are any design patterns, guidelines, tutorials that can help with the process?

Comment: It is intuitively simple enough but by the time you made it pretty you'll have wasted a month or two of your life.  Buy, don't build, google "silverlight chart control".

Comment: I wish I could use ready made controls, but unfortunately it has to be from scratch as we have to be able to reuse XAML for embedded Silverlight (with the backend written in C++). Right now, though, it just has to work with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a [the Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). It is open-source and has chart controls written by Microsoft. This is probably the closest thing to design guidelines you can get.

Comment: I had a look at it and felt a bit overwhelmed. Was hoping for something at a higher abstraction, but ok, I guess I have to put up my sleeves and start digging.  My hope was that there was something in the veins of the GoF Design Patterns or Martin Fowlers Enterprise Patterns or some kind of standard in how to approach chart design. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think the GoF Design Patterns probably apply to Chart Design as well :)

Comment: Sure as it also applies to Enterprise development ;-)  Just out of curiosity, which patterns from GoF would you consider most suitable for chart designs? Of course Composite is the most obvious for the Axis and Series components and maybe Facade to hide the complexities and Template to reuse code to draw different types of chart. What gives me headaches is the sheer number of ways one can render a chart and all those various configuration options one has to provide to make it look right. How to do all this without getting into a huge mess?